# Are there any dependencies for unrevoked3 to run on stock ubuntu?

Tags: linux, htc-droid-incredible, unrevoked

I cannot get unrevoked 3 to run on either my laptop or desktop which both run 64 bit Ubuntu.

Is there a dependency I need?

I download and extract to ~/Downloads

```
cd ~/Downloads
gksu ./reflash
```

...and nothing happens.

Based on [this Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10660137&postcount=13) thread, it seems to be a conflict between 32/64 bit. Is there a way to get this 32 bit application working on my 64 bit system?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? I see AskUbuntu does have (at least) one question that could be relevant, [Running 32-bit app under 64-bit linux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20355/running-32-bit-app-under-64-bit-linux), but I'm not sure if the answers there will help you get Unrevoked working, specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unrevoked needs 32bit. That is all.

I ran it on a 32 bit live cd.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run it under Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit after installing the 32-bit shared libraries:

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`